# How can I get an updated $Revision$ in my code

Tags: svn, keyword-substitution

I have a project into which I'd like to embed the revision number automagically.

In this case, it's a multi-file perl script. In the main file, I have a line that looks like this:

my $revision = '$Revision: 24 $';

When I make a release, I checkout the project to my release dir.

The revision number does change whenever I check-in a change to THAT FILE. The $Revision$ attribute is updated on check-in, but not check-out.

The thing is, the main file doesn't change that often, so even though the other files in the project are now at 27, the main still has 24.

Is there a way that I can get the main file to reflect the latest rev number? The one that svn prints out at the end of the checkout, ie "Checked out revision 27."

Comment: Take a look at the svnversion command.  What you want to do will likely required a post-processing step.

Answer (score 2):

It is similar to CVS, you can use $Revision$ you just have to set the keyword property for that file for SVN to know it is supposed to do a keyword replace.

From the manual:

"With no svn:keywords property set on that file, Subversion will do nothing special. Now, 
let's enable substitution of the LastChangedDate keyword. 
$ svn propset svn:keywords "Date Author" weather.txt 
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'weather.txt' 
$ 
"

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.pdf

Comment: While true and informative, this does not even come close to answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! -e '.version')
{
    open VERSION, '>.version';
    print VERSION `svnversion -n | cut -f1 -d:`;
    close VERSION;
}

my $revision = '$Revision: ' . `cat .version` . ' $';
```

(**Note:** a puppy will die if you use this code as-is)

Comment: Why not directly use the output of the svnversion command instead of creating a temporary file?

Comment: In case you didn't want to run 'svnversion' each time your script ran.